# Python, sum returned MySQL data

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

'm fetching some data from MySQL database using:

```
cur.execute("SELECT memory FROM vm WHERE hv_id=5")
for row in cur.fetchall() :
print row[0]
```

This prints something like this:

```
512
1024
4096
4096
2048
4096
1024
6144
1024
1024
4096
```

I need sum the above and set it as a variable for further calculations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't use `SUM()` in the query itself:

```
cur.execute("SELECT SUM(memory) FROM vm WHERE hv_id=5")
result = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

another answer if you are finding something **Pythonista**

```
cur.execute("SELECT memory FROM vm WHERE hv_id=5")
result = sum(int(x) for x in cur.fetchall())
print result
```

or

```
result = sum(map(int, cur.fetchall()))
```